# JS Date comparison CET with GMT

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't understand...

I have the following code:

```
console.log(stats.mtime); // Tue Dec 30 2014 17:03:48 GMT+0100 (CET)
console.log(s3Info.LastModified); // Tue, 30 Dec 2014 15:46:37 GMT
console.log(stats.mtime == s3Info.LastModified); // false
console.log(stats.mtime > s3Info.LastModified); // false
console.log(stats.mtime < s3Info.LastModified); // false
```

How can I compare those dates? I tried to convert to timestamps but it won't work. I get a `TypeError: Object Tue, 30 Dec 2014 15:46:37 GMT has no method 'getTime' error.`

Using nodejs but (hopefully) the answer would be similar clientside.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using something like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com)? It works both client-side and server-side and it is on npm.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't have actual `Date` objects but only strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about comparing the unix time like:

```
stats.mtime.getTime() === s3Info.LastModified.valueOf()
```

im assuming the `stats` as in `fs` stat, and `LastModified` as the JS Date obj

Comment: In my case `s3Info.LastModified` was a string, hence the final solution has been: `new Date(s3Info.LastModified).valueOf()`. Thanks!